# Robbery database monthly average query with sqlite

Tags: database

I'm using sqlite. I have a database table (robbery) that stores when and where a robbery happened. The robbery table has these attributes: date, city, id (PK). The date is the day when the robbery happened (each row means one robbery).

[image]

The dates are stored in the robbery table in this format: 2017-07-01

I'm trying to get this information: ***Sum of the robberies that happened each months in this period: between 2016-07 and 2017-02.***

For example from the attached database, **I would like to get this result with a query:**

```html
2016-08: 2
2016-09: 1
2017-02: 1
```

Comment: Refer to the note about using ISO-8601 date formats like "yyyy-mm-dd" from my answer to your earlier question. Another advantage to them, besides working with sqlite date and time functions, is that they can be sorted properly, unlike "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: Thanks! They were already in that format, I just can't make excel show them in that format...

Comment: You should provide sample data that's in the same format as your real data. What's excel got to do with anything? You're working with SQL, not a spreadsheet. And show what you've tried so far - this is starting to look like you're just trying to get people to do your homework for you.

Comment: It's not homework, I'm just practicing for an exam and I have some sample questions to practice, this is one of them. The other ones I can solve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following will do what you wish (dates are different for my convenience, wasn't going to add all the dates shown in the question) :-

```
SELECT substr(date,1,7)||':' AS Date, count() AS number_of_robberies 
FROM robbery 
WHERE datetime(date) BETWEEN datetime('2016-01-01') AND datetime('2017-02-28')
GROUP BY substr(datetime(date),1,7)
;
```

using the following (to load some data) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS robbery;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS robbery (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, city TEXT, date TEXT);
INSERT INTO robbery (city,date) VALUES
    ('Chicago','2018-01-01'),('New York','2017-03-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-02-01'),('New York','2018-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-02-01'),('New York','2018-03-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-02-01'),('New York','2017-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-03-01'),('New York','2018-03-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-03-01'),('New York','2018-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-03-01'),('New York','2017-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2016-01-01'),('New York','2017-03-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-02-01'),('New York','2018-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2017-02-01'),('New York','2018-03-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-02-01'),('New York','2016-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2016-03-01'),('New York','2016-03-21'),
    ('Chicago','2016-03-01'),('New York','2018-01-21'),
    ('Chicago','2018-03-01'),('New York','2018-01-21');

SELECT substr(date,1,7)||':' AS Date, count() AS number_of_robberies 
FROM robbery 
WHERE datetime(date) BETWEEN datetime('2016-01-01') AND datetime('2017-02-28')
GROUP BY substr(datetime(date),1,7)
;
```

Results in :-

[image]

- Note months where there are no robberies wouldn't be displayed (as can be seen).